# Wie durchkoppeln bei Abkürzungen/Akronymen in Klammern? – How to link through abbreviations/acronyms with brackets?

Tags: spelling, punctuation, abbreviation, reformed-orthography

(Deutsche Version unten)

### Background

I do use LaTeX to write a document and use the `acro` package, which provides a way to define acronyms/abbrevations in your document, to specify acronyms there. It e.g. handles the first case of a printed acronym, so it automatically writes the short and long form  in brackets then, e.g. "ICE (Intercity-Express)".

In the [manual of acro v2.10c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v2.10/acro_en.pdf) page 27, or [nearly the same on p. 28 ff. of v3.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v3.2/doc/acro-manual.pdf), it states something about German orthography, i.e. it says:

> Let’s say you’re a German chemist and you have [Polyurethan]
> and you use it the first time like this:
> `\ac{PU}-Hartschaum`
> then according to German orthography and typesetting rules this should be printed as
>
> > “Polyurethan(PU)-Hartschaum”
>
> i. e., with *no* space between long and short form.

**Edit:** The author replied to me and the source is actually [this Duden article](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Klammern-und-Bindestrich):

> Mittlerweile ist es auch üblich, innerhalb von Wortzusammensetzungen mit Bindestrich in Klammern die Abkürzung eines vorgenannten Begriffes einzufügen. In solch einem Fall wird die Klammer ohne Leerschritt angefügt und der Bindestrich nach der Klammer gesetzt: Polyurethan(PU)-Hartschaum, Rot-Weiß-Oberhausen(RWO)-Fanartikel.

In English:

> It is now also common practice to insert the abbreviation of a previously mentioned term within word compositions with a hyphen in brackets. In such a case, the parenthesis is added without a space and the hyphen is placed after the parenthesis: Polyurethane (PU) rigid foam, Rot-Weiß-Oberhausen(RWO) fan article.

(Translated with the free version of [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com))

My examples below still are somewhat strange, IMHO.

### Question

**Now I doubt whether it is true – and, if it is, I'd like to see a source for this.**

Basically, I'd say this is a version of [Durchkoppeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung), or “Zusammensetzungen durch Bindestriche”, but with the special case that you need to specify something in brackets `()`  there…
So should one put a space there or not?

Here are some examples this applies to…

> WLAN(Wireless Local Area Network)-Passwort
> WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network)-Passwort

Also slight varions like the order or using quotes don't change the question:

> „Wireless Local Area Network”(WLAN)-Passwort
> „Wireless Local Area Network” (WLAN)-Passwort

Another example:

> EU(Europäische Union)-Binnenmarkt

Or:

> TLS(Transport Layer Security)-Zertifikate

Or:

> „Universal Serial Bus“(USB)-Stick

Or another German example:

> Coronavirus-Krankheit-2019(COVID-19)-Pandemie

---

## German version / Deutscher Text

---

### Hintergrund

Ich benutze LaTeX, um ein Dokument zu schreiben, und benutze das `acro`-Paket, das eine Möglichkeit bietet, Akronyme/Abkürzungen im Dokument zu definieren, um dort Akronyme anzugeben. Es behandelt z.B. den ersten Fall eines ausgegegbenen Akronyms, sodass es automatisch die Kurz- und Langform in Klammern schreibt, z.B. "ICE (Intercity-Express)".

Im [Handbuch zu acro v2.10c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v2.10/acro_en.pdf) Seite 27, oder [fast gleichlautend auf S. 28 ff. von v3.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v3.2/doc/acro-manual.pdf), steht etwas über die deutsche Rechtschreibung, d.h. es steht dort:

> Nehmen wir an, Sie sind ein deutscher Chemiker und Sie haben [Polyurethan]
> und Sie verwenden es zum ersten Mal so:
> `\ac{PU}-Hartschaum`
> dann sollte dies nach den deutschen Rechtschreib- und Satzregeln gedruckt werden als
>
> > "Polyurethan(PU)-Hartschaum".
>
> d. h., mit *keinem* Zwischenraum zwischen Lang- und Kurzform.

(Übersetzt mit Hilfe der kostenlosen Version von [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com))

**Edit:** Der Autor hat mir geantwortet und die Quelle ist eigentlich [dieser Duden-Artikel](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Klammern-und-Bindestrich):

> Mittlerweile ist es auch üblich, innerhalb von Wortzusammensetzungen mit Bindestrich in Klammern die Abkürzung eines vorgenannten Begriffes einzufügen. In solch einem einem Fall wird die Klammer ohne Leerschritt angefügt und der Bindestrich nach der Klammer gesetzt: Polyurethan(PU)-Hartschaum, Rot-Weiß-Oberhausen(RWO)-Fanartikel.

Meine Beispiele unten sind immer noch etwas seltsam, IMHO.

### Frage

**Nun bezweifle ich, ob das wahr ist – und, wenn es wahr ist, würde ich gerne eine Quelle dafür sehen.**

Im Grunde würde ich sagen, dies ist eine Version des [Durchkoppelns](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung), oder „Zusammensetzungen durch Bindestriche”, aber mit dem speziellen Fall, dass man dort etwas in Klammern `()` angeben muss...
Sollte man dort also ein Leerzeichen setzen oder nicht?

Hier sind einige Beispiele, auf die dies zutrifft...

> WLAN(Wireless Local Area Network)-Passwort
> WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network)-Passwort

Auch geringfügige Abweichungen an der Reihenfolge oder die Verwendung von Anführungszeichen ändern nichts an der Frage der Zeichensetzung:

> "Wireless Local Area Network"(WLAN)-Passwort
> "Wireless Local Area Network" (WLAN)-Passwort

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> EU(Europäische Union)-Binnenmarkt

Oder:

> TLS(Transport Layer Security)-Zertifikat

Oder:

> "Universeller serieller Bus"(USB)-Stick

Oder ein anderes deutsches Beispiel:

> Coronavirus-Krankheit-2019(COVID-19)-Pandemie

Comment: Duden hin oder her, ich halte es für keine leserfreundliche Lösung, im Textfluss wahlweise Abkürzungen zu definieren oder zu erklären. Warum kommen Fußnoten oder Verweise auf ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis nicht in Frage?

Comment: Welche Funktion sollen die Anführungsstriche übernehmen?

Comment: @userunknown: mit Anführungsstrichen kann ich (laienhaft ausgedrückt) eine Wortgruppe mit Leerzeichen statt Bindestrichen zusammenhalten und durchkoppeln. Z.B. um Aktionsnamen zu erhalten: das ist die "Ich bin heute ein toller Mensch!"-Aktion. M.E. leider tendieren Firmen für ihr Markenheiligtum dazu: die McDonald's WM Kinder-Initiative. (oder so ähnlich 2006 gesehen) Statt: die "McDonald's WM-Kinder"-Initiative oder die McDonald's-WM-Kinder-Initiative.

Comment: @guidot: zu meiner Zeit des wissenschaftlichen Tuns war die Sache klar: so oder so, hauptsache einheitlich. Und jede Abkürzung, die über sehr generisches "bzw." hinaus ging, musste bei der erstmaligen Verwendung des Wortes im Testkörper angegeben werden. Hat für mich den Vorteil, dass ich beim Kapitel 3 mit PU-Schaum dann den Text nach vorne abscanne auf PU und schwups finde ich die erstmalige Verwendung samt Ausschreibung.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Die McDonalds-WM-Kinder-Initiative, mit Bindestrichen durchkoppeln, nicht mit Anführungszeichen.

Comment: Hier zeigt sich, dass die korrekte(?) Lösung zu Fürchterlichkeiten führen kann. Umformulierungen a la "Um sich am WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network) anzumelden, benötigt man ein WLAN-Passwort" steigern möglivcherweise die Leserlichkeit enorm

Answer (score 2):

Soweit ich den Wikieintrag bzw. den Duden-Eintrag verstehe, ist Sinn und Zweck des Kopplungsstrichs, die einzelnen Wörter in einer Kette zu verbinden und gleichzeitig abzugrenzen:

> „In einer Aneinanderreihung aus einem Grundwort und mehreren Bestimmungswörtern werden alle Wörter durch Bindestriche verbunden (durchgekoppelt).“ ([Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchkopplung))

> In Aneinanderreihungen und Zusammensetzungen mit Wortgruppen setzt man Bindestriche zwischen die einzelnen Wörter. Das gilt auch, wenn Buchstaben, Ziffern oder Abkürzungen Teile einer Zusammensetzung sind <§§ 43, 44, 45 E2>. ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#D26))

Damit wäre "Polyurethan (PU)" alleinstehend mit Leerzeichen und "Polyurethan(PU)-Schaum" durchgekoppelt ohne Leerzeichen. Denn "(PU)" ist m.E. kein alleinstehendes Wort. Die [Duden-Klammerregeln](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/klammern) sagen nichts explizit dazu.

Edit: OP hat die relevante Regel während meines Antwortschreibens selbst eingefügt, [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Klammern-und-Bindestrich):

> In solch einem Fall wird die Klammer ohne Leerschritt angefügt und der Bindestrich nach der Klammer gesetzt: Polyurethan(PU)-Hartschaum, Rot-Weiß-Oberhausen(RWO)-Fanartikel.